# Trigger QuerySubmitted once

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a AutoSuggestBox with QuerySubmitted property, so when I hit enter button , it will search for products and will show error message when no data found , my problem is it will show twice or multiple times when i hit enter multiple times too.

here is my code:

```
        try {
            if (!ViewModel.IsBusy) {
                ViewModel.IsBusy = true;
                await this.ViewModel.FindAsync(args.QueryText);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }
        finally { 
            ViewModel.IsBusy = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because the second call to your function is making the bool false and hence the 3rd call will go into if condition and will do a FindAsync()

Instead you can do this :

```
try {
        if (!ViewModel.IsBusy) {
            ViewModel.IsBusy = true;
            await this.ViewModel.FindAsync(args.QueryText);
            ViewModel.IsBusy = false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
       ViewModel.IsBusy = false;
    }
```

Or you can really use [Task Cancellation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396(v=vs.110).aspx) for better design and you will get the benefit of sending the latest args.QueryText to the FindAsync if there are changes in querytext between multiple Enter key hit. Of course, you need to cancel the earlier Task if you encounter that there is a new call.

Comment: It worked! , let me try that Task Cancellation 

Thank You